# Visual Basic 6.0 & MS Excel 2003

Tags: excel, vb6

Is there any tool or code that would enable me to Display Excel 2003 Sheet "or part of it" in Visual Basic 6.0 Form so it could be editable in vb 6.0 runtime environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these ...

[كيفية تضمين أتمتة مستندات مع Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242243)

[Visual Basic 6.0--- To import excel File to display in datagrid](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=360553)

[Embed Excel in VB 6 and Automating Excel](http://www.edrawsoft.com/embed-excel-vb.php)

Answer (score 1):

The [OLE control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267228%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) is designed to allow embedding of other applications and their data in your application.

Comment: you can not save changes to a previously created excel Sheet embedded by OLE Object ...  Can you ?!

Comment: Thank you i get it now, but in some example about the Monitor (Display) the code was :

Dim DC As Long
    DC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", vbNullString, vbNullString, 0&)

My q. now is, what is (0&) ??

As far as i understood it represents the DevMode of the Device, but what is it still (0&) ?!